# Build GDB for multiple architectures

Tags: gdb, mingw

I want to build gdb for Windows and target it to multiple Linux architectures.

I've successfully built gdb for windows which target aarch64-linux-gnu with next command

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
```

But couldn't target it to multiple architectures.

The gdb documentation says that there is option **--enable-targets**
But

```
./configure --help
```

Doesn't print such option.

My final goal is gdb for Windows and target it to aarch64-linux-gnu and x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
What should I do for that?

Comment: Did you check `gdb/configure --help`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, for GDB specific configure options you need `gdb/configure --help`.

For your particular question though, what you need is the `--enable-targets=all` configure option.

The `--enable-targets` option either takes the special keyword `all`, or it takes a comma separated list of additional targets to support.  Targets specified in `--enable-targets` are always in addition to the target specified with `--target=...`.

Comment: So, you are right.  `gdb/configure --help` print info about `--enable-targets`.
But it's unclear what arguments should I pass? Should I skip `--target` argument?
I've tried `--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=aarch64-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`
But in config.status file I see `S["target"]="x86_64-w64-mingw32"`

Comment: I think that the configure scripts expect a `--target` option, and if you don't supply one it'll set things up so `--target` is the same as `--host`.  Then GDB builds with support for all the targets in `--target` and the comma separated list in `--enable-targets`.  If you want to support both your host system and a limited set of remote systems, I'd place the host system type in `--target` and the extra systems in `--enable-targets`.

Comment: It works) Call with next arguments `--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-targets=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.

Thank you